# Silex redirect with argument

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, silex

I need to redirect from a controller to another.

```
$app->get('/test', function(Request $request) use ($app) {

    return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("success", [
        "myArg" => $myArg
    ]));
});


$app->get('/test/success', function(Request $request, $myArg) use ($app) {

    return $app['twig']->render('confirmation.twig', [
        'myArg' => $myArg,
    ]);
})->bind('success');
```

But it seems to doesn't be the good way to do it... I just want to redirect to the route "/test/success" and passing the $myArg variable to my confirmation.twig template.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Store the variable in session?

Answer (score 2):

By putting $myArg in the arguments of your function, Silex expects it to be a parameter from your URL, however your [route definition isn't dynamic](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#dynamic-routing) so it can't work.

If you want to get the parameter from the arguments of your function you have to modify your route definition to something like `/test/success/{myArg}`.

Comment: I need a URL as neutral as possible, so without custom variables. And $myArg is a boolean.

Comment: Silex won't call directly your other function, it will tell your browser to do it, so you can't pass a boolean, it will be converted to a string value.

Since you don't want to put myArg as a parameter of your URL, the URL generator will add it as a query string to your URL. So your URL will look like ``/test/success?myArg=1``.

If you want to retrieve its value from your action your will have to pass the request to your function and and do ``$request->get('myArg');``. Then you will need to convert the string value to a boolean.